# ionic issue - displaying white screen before launcher screen comes

Tags: ionic-framework

I am facing issue in ionic framework. Every time one white screen appears before coming the actual splash or launcher screen?

Any solution available for this?

Thanks
Shyam

Comment: I had same issue, since last 6 month there is nothing solution. kindly share solution if anybody has...